# How to merge two data by different column names?

Tags: r, join

I have two different tables:

Table 1:

```
#     id1   value price sales
# 1:  c001   100   500    20
# 2:  c002   200   200    30
# 3:  c003   300   400    15
```

Table 2:

```
#     id2   nr 
# 1: c001   50   
# 2: c002   23    
# 3: c003   41
```

Now I try to join table 1 with table 2 by id1 and id2...

```
full_join <- merge(table1, table2, by.x="id1", by.y="id2", all = TRUE)
```

I get following result:

```
#     id1   value price sales  nr
# 1:  c001   100   500    20   50
# 2:  c002   200   200    30   23
# 3:  c003   300   400    15   41
```

But I want to keep all columns. It should look like:

```
 #     id1   id2   value price sales  nr
 # 1:  c001   c001  100   500    20   50
 # 2:  c002   c002  200   200    30   23
 # 3:  c003   c003  300   400    15   41
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to keep id1 and id2 as you are sure they are the same ?

Comment: The dplyr join methods work in the same way. If you absolutely want the column something like `table2$id1 <- table2$id2;  full_join <- merge(table1, table2, by.x="id1", by.y="id1", all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to merge the 2 datas you can simply do:

```
full_table <- cbind(table1, table2)
```

But if you want to match the values your answer is right, but I just don't know why you want to keep the column if the values are the same.